# SpringMvc RequestBody getting headers

Tags: json, spring-mvc, post

I am using SpringMVC and this is my POST method:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/test/handler", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
        headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
    public String getOpen(@RequestBody String json, HttpServletRequest request) throws InterruptedException {

        String result= json;                        

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DataJsonMailJet jsonobj = null;
        try {

            // read from file, convert it to jsonobj class
            jsonobj = mapper.readValue(json, DataJsonMailJet.class);

            // display to console
            System.out.println(jsonobj);

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    return (result);

    }
```

The Problem is that my "json" object is even getting the header like so:

```
------------------------------2fe344dd21f3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"

[{"event":"open","time":1467369924, .......}]
------------------------------2fe344dd21f3--
```

I Have tried taking out the "headers" but no luck...
Any Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/handler", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getOpen(
        @RequestHeader(value="Accept") String accept,
        @RequestHeader(value="Content-Type") String contentType,
        @RequestBody String json,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error:
Missing header 'Content-Disposition' for method parameter type [java.lang.String] - Missing header 'Content-Disposition' for method parameter type [java.lang.String]

Comment: @Kunal - Please remove it and try again, Content-Disposition is a response header, if needed we need to set this header while sending the response.

Comment: I managed to solve the error thanks! It was a fault from the request sender. They were having some problems and the header was included in the  body... Thanks!